# What is needed to create a HDMI output

Tags: lcd, hdmi

I am experimenting with the arm cortex A8, it has a bunch of LCD outputs I first thought I could just convert LCD to a HDMI signal, but can't seem to find any thing of an use, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Beaglebone Black uses an NXP TDA19988BHN/C1 to convert the LCD outputs from the TI A8 processor to HDMI. See http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/NXP_TDA19988-838481.pdf

Answer (score 1):

HDMI is a high speed serial bus. If you chip does not directly support HDMI, then you will probably have to use an FPGA of some sort to generate it. An HDMI port all by itself is not so useful either, you will need at least a hardware DMA engine to drive it and/or a whole GPU. These can be implemented on an FPGA, the hard part may be finding an interface into system RAM with enough bandwidth. I would recommend finding a different chip that is capable of directly driving HDMI, otherwise this will be very expensive in both time and money.

Edit: now that you have actually mentioned what chip you're using, I can offer a more useful answer. That particular chip has a parallel LCD interface that can be used to drive video data to a TFT LCD with a compatible driver. Thus, the chip does not have the necessary serializers to drive HDMI directly, but it can drive video data. All that needs to be done is convert the format. However, this is a solved problem - the beaglebone already has circuitry to do this, it's just a matter of taking a look at the schematic. That board uses a TDA19988, so I would recommend duplicating the relevant portion of the schematic so you will get the same functionality.  See page 10 of https://github.com/CircuitCo/BeagleBone-Black/blob/master/BBB_SCH.pdf?raw=true .

Comment: Okay thank you, do you happen to  know of any that support HDMI? also, can the LCD system be converted to something basic that can work with a HDMI port?

Comment: Whatever is used on the raspberry pi/beagle bone/etc should support it.  It would not be simple to convert an "LCD interface" to HDMI , unless the "LCD interface" is an LVDS interface to a TFT panel.  I presume your chip is set up to direct-drive raw LCD segments.  In which case, converting it would at minimum require an FPGA, and it would probably be extremely limited in resolution (i.e. 640x480 if you're really, really lucky).

Comment: I am using the same chip as the Beaglebone black, the a8 has a onboard GPU.

Comment: The beaglebone black is open source, why don't you just use it as a reference design and duplicate the relevant portion of the schematic? Looks like they use a TDA19988 to do the conversion.